# Goodness of fit likelihood ratio test with zero values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio

I have a vector of observed frequencies that have zero values in some cells and a vector of expected frequencies generated by a model. I would like to do a likelihood ratio test rather than a chi squared test  because I have different nested models and would like to use $2 \ln\cal{L}$ difference to evaluate the models.

My question is how to deal with the zero cells? Is it sensible to remove the contribution from the 0 cell like in the R-code below? Or should I combine cells or do a continuity correction?

Example:

```
observed <- c(142,34,18,15,12,136,6,7,2,3,2,1,1,0,2)
expected <- c(141.99,53.33,32.59,23.66,18.78,15.77,13.75,12.33,11.3,10.54,
               9.98,9.57,9.29,9.1,9.02)

2 * (sum(observed * log(observed/expected), na.rm=TRUE))

[1] 455.8816
```

Comment: Note $x\log{x}$ tends to zero as $x$ does.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to combine cells or try some continuity correction, you can compute the likelihood - and hence the statistic - quite readily.

$G = 2\sum_{i} {O_{i} \cdot \ln\left(\frac{O_i}{E_i}\right)}$

Since $\lim_{x\to 0}x \ln x=0\,$, each cell with a 0 count contributes $0 \log (0/E_i)=0$  to the sum in the formula for $G$.

So you can just skip the zero cells, or equivalently you can replace their contribution with 0.

See also Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test), where it says of this test:

> the sum is taken over all non-empty cells.

Consequently (as long as the NAs correspond to the empty cells) the R code that just omits the `NA`s is correct.

---

On the other hand, you can very often compare nested models via chi-squared, since the chi-square will generally partition into components that allow for testing the change - you just get another chi-square test.